# Google Cloud Storage bucket throws error "The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, gcloud, bucket, google-cloud-billing

I already checked my project and it has an active
[billing account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKKrd.png)

I am using node js

```
var gcloud    = require('gcloud');
var gcs = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: config.gcloud.projectid,
  keyFilename: config.gcloud.keyfilename
});
var bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);   
bucket.upload(filePath, fileOptions, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {        
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("success")
        }
      });
```

This was working before. I'm not sure why it is returning an error. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is the bucket you're copying from outside of your project? If you're copying a file from another project, they're charged the usage fee unless the bucket is marked as 'requester pays'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Based on my research please find below the possible scenarios of the error message you provided:

1. If you are using [Cloud Platform Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/) you may have run out of [Cloud Storage Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free). In that case, you may consider upgrading your account to a paid one to potentially resolve the issue.
2. This error may also occur because of the Cloud Storage bucket you are trying to use does not exist.  You may verify this by clicking the blue button titled [“Open the Cloud Storage Browser”](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets).
3. If you have a paid account and the Cloud Storage bucket does exist, please open a Billing Support Request using the Billing Support Requests form provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/#contact_support).

Comment: Ugg. what a waste of time.  For me the problem was #2.  Hard to imagine a more misleading error message.

Comment: #2 was the cause for me too.

Comment: Currently (11,13.2022), the blue button which was titled “Open the Cloud Storage Browser” (solution #2) is now called "Go to Buckets".

Answer (score -1):

Please try below steps for resolving the issue:

1. Select appropriate project
2. Search 'Cloud Storage'
3. Click 'Create Bucket' and create new bucket under cloud storage

Make sure your experiment is referring the newly created storage. I was referring the storage location through config file, here how it goes:

--> Config.py

```
gs_bucket_name="kubeflow_demo_storage"
Bucket_uri="gs://data-labeling-demo"
version=1
store_artifacts=Bucket_uri + "/" + str(version)
data_path=Bucket_uri + "/" + "data/data_raw.csv"
processed_data=Bucket_uri + "/" + "processed/data_processed.csv"
```

Answer (score -1):

`UserProjectAccountProblem`
The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account.
The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed

Comment: auto generated spam