# Firebase storage in free plan: The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a picture to my firebase storage account, but whenever I run the code, I am having a 403 HTTP error: "The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account". **Note that I am using the free subscription (spark plan), so this question is not similar to**: [Google Cloud Storage bucket throws error "The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829042/google-cloud-storage-bucket-throws-error-the-project-to-be-billed-is-associated)

A more verbose error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "accountDisabled",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is my code in Python:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage
import os


cred = credentials.Certificate(os.getenv("FIREBASE_CREDS"))
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
bucket = storage.bucket('profile_pictures')
blob = bucket.blob("test_image.jpg")
blob.upload_from_string(test_image_path)
```

Is the problem coming from my python code, or from some settings I need to fix in firebase?
With the Spark plan, we are supposed to have some free storage (and for now, I didn't store anything ...)

Comment: Are you sure that `profile_pictures` is a bucket name and not a "folder" name (you can see folders in the Firebase console but they are not real folders, just generated from a slash separated file name)? Can you show a picture of your Firebase Cloud Storage console?

Comment: it's definitely a folder name! I don't see any other values I could give ?

Comment: Ok that was the issue ... in bucket, I should have give my appspot url. And then in bucket.blob: "folder_name/picture_name". If I may, I think the HTTP error message is misleading !! But thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you mix up "bucket" and "filename".

You need to pass the following value to the `storage.bucket()` method: `gs://[your-project-id].appspot.com`

**and**

you need to pass the full file name to `bucket.blob()`, including the "folder" part.

---

Note that you can see folders in the Firebase console but, actually, they are not real folders: They are just generated from slash separated file names, in order to ease the navigation in the Firebase console.